# SQL command from variable in ole db source not reevaluate in foreach loop container

Tags: ssis

I have a data flow task in my foreach loop container. Every round, I reassign 3 varaiables: `User::Date`, `User::Location`, and `User::Organization`. I have another variable `User:Query` that has an expression using these variables in where clause.
I use this `User:Query` in the OLE DB Source of the data flow task, but in each foreach round, it uses the same default values for these variables. Why?

OLE DB Provider: OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 10.0
And on break point, I can see the query variable is actually showing correct, but the source doesn't use the updated variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out: I didn't change `EvaluateAsExpression` property to True for my `User::Query` variable.